# angualr2 deploy in host sever

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to make my angular2 project in sub folder like (www.example.com/dist), I am trying to build my angualr2 project, Using **ng build command**, I got error shown at below. please help me to solve this problem,

**dist/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mini Project</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**dist folder structure**

http://pmscreative.com/dist/assets/image/Capture1.JPG

**ERROR**

http://pmscreative.com/dist/assets/image/Capture.JPG

Comment: Try to use `<base href="/dist/">` in `index.html`.

Comment: Images not found. Please edit your question and show your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because Angular automatically points the URLs at the root (such as, /3urhfu9ewhfu2i34nf2.bundle.js). You should either follow best practice, and deploy in the root folder, or change the link and script references in the compiled `index.html`.